# Set of quadratic forms that represents all primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms, class-field-theory

**A SPECIFIC CASE:**

Any prime number can be classified as either $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

If $p = 3$ or $p = 1 \pmod 3$, then the prime $p$ can be represented by the quadratic form $ x^2 + 3y^2, x,y \in \mathbb Z.$

But what if $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$?

Is there a quadratic form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ such that $p= ax^2+bxy+cy^2, $ when $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ where $x,y, a, b,c  \in \mathbb Z$?

**GENERAL CASE:**

The general question is, is there a set of quadratic forms which represent all prime numbers?

We will classify the prime numbers, say, by $m$. Any prime is defined by $p \equiv i \pmod m$ where $1 \leq i\leq m-1$.

In  above example, $i \in \{1, 2\}, m=3$. Let, the set of quadratic forms is $A$, then the number of elements in $A$ is at-least $(m-1)$.

**QUESTION:**

For a given $m$ can we find a set $A$  such that any prime $p$ can be represented by one of the quadratic form of $A$ ?

If it is possible then how? If there is a condition on $m$, what is it?

Does the question has any relation to the following theorem ?

[image]

One can answer only the specific case, if they wish to do so.

**EDIT:**

Is there a finite set of (preferably irreducible) binary quadratic forms such that every prime is represented by **at least one of the forms** in the set?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that for any primitive quadratic form and any $m>0$, the form represents infinitely many primes which are $1\pmod m$. This should follow from Chebotarev's density theorem. Therefore there cannot be such a form which only represents non-1 residues modulo a number.

Comment: Actually on second reading, you didn't ask for the form to *only* represent the forms of specific residue. In that case there are some trivial examples, like the form $xy$, or $x^2-y^2$. I'm not sure if you can do with only irreducible forms.

Comment: If a quadratic form represents $p$, then the discriminant $b^2 -4ac$ of the form is a perfect square modulo $p$. (Proof: The discriminant is invariant under change of variables. Because the form represents $p$, we can change variables so that $a=p$.) So indeed no non-split form represents all primes and sets like the set of primes congruent to $2$ mod $3$ can never be represented.

Comment: You can certainly get all primes if you are willing to accept overlap between the different quadratic forms.

Comment: I read the question as permitting overlap. I think the question is, is there a finite set of (preferably irreducible) binary quadratic forms such that every prime is represented by at least one of the forms in the set?

Comment: @WillSawin yes overlap is allowed, then, for example, how we find quadratic forms that represents all primes defined by $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are correct, then what is the solution and where I can find related results?

Comment: @Andrew: Every prime $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ is represented by $x^2+y^2$ or $3x^2-y^2$. See my response for more detail.

Comment: This is really not a question for MO, but for MSE.

Comment: @Servaes  first posted at MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820129/non-linear-forms-for-all-prime-numbers

Comment: @WillJagy that was very helpful, this time I was looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every prime $p$ is represented by at least one of the following quadratic forms: $x^2+y^2$, $x^2+3y^2$, $3x^2-y^2$:

- if $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $p$ is represented by $x^2+y^2$;
- if $p=3$ or $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, then $p$ is represented by $x^2+3y^2$;
- if $p\equiv 11\pmod{12}$, then $p$ is represented by $3x^2-y^2$.

This follows from Lemma 2.5, Corollary 2.6, (page 26) in [Cox](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=tlTZC-k-l2EC&oi=fnd&pg=PR4&dq=Primes%20of%20the%20Form%20x2%2Bny2:%20Fermat,%20Class%20Field%20Theory,%20and%20Complex%20Multiplication&ots=OhvI9HUpzP&sig=zHs4S21VPGD3-xrzfG2YOsfLFVM#v=onepage&q=Primes%20of%20the%20Form%20x2%2Bny2%3A%20Fermat%2C%20Class%20Field%20Theory%2C%20and%20Complex%20Multiplication&f=false): Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$ coupled with the fact that $x^2+y^2$, $x^2+3y^2$, $3x^2-y^2$, $x^2-3y^2$ represent all integral binary quadratic forms of discriminant lying in $\{-4,\pm 12\}$.

**Added.** More generally, if an odd number of discriminants multiply to a square, then the quadratic forms of those discriminants together represent all primes coprime to those discriminants. In the example above, the discriminants were the elements of $\{-4,\pm 12\}$, and we could do without the form $x^2-3y^2$. See also this [related post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373900/reference-for-no-finite-set-of-positive-integer-binary-quadratic-forms-repres).

Comment: I gave him $x^2 + y^2, x^2+ 2 y^2, x^2 - 2 y^2$ at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820129/non-linear-forms-for-all-prime-numbers  and suggested he read Dickson's little 1929 book Intro to.. It would appear he refuses to do that. The claim I made there, no finite set of positive binaries could work, is something for which I lack a proof.

Comment: posted a new question here on MO about the finiteness claim.