# Is every prime $q$ of the form $x^2 + py^2$ for some prime $p<q$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For every odd prime $q \geq 3$, does there exist a prime $p < q$ and integers $x,y$ such that

$$\displaystyle x^2 + py^2 = q?$$

One can easily show that all primes $q \not \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ can be written as such a sum. Indeed, if $q \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ then $q$ is the norm of an element in the ring of Eisenstein integers, so there exist integers $x,y$ such that $q = x^2 + xy + y^2$. If $xy \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, say $2 | y$, then we can write

$$\displaystyle q = \left(x + \frac{y}{2} \right)^2 + 3 \left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^2,$$

so we are done. Otherwise we must have $x,y$ are both odd. Now note that $q = x^2 + xy + y^2$ implies that

$$\displaystyle q = (-x - y)^2 + y(-x - y) + y^2,$$

and $x + y$ is even.

Playing similar games for other small primes of class number one gives that at least half of odd primes can be expressed in the form above.

Comment: $x = 0, y = 1, p = q$?

Comment: not sure, but see  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373900/reference-for-no-finite-set-of-positive-integer-binary-quadratic-forms-repres  Suggest including $x^2 + y^2.$ That way you get $5.$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes that is a careless oversight. I added the restriction that $p < q$.

Comment: There is a [**book**](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf) by D Cox quite relevant to your question...

Comment: $q:=2= 0^2+2\cdot1^2\ $ is fine too.

Comment: getting somewhere. There are infinitely many positive integers that are not the sum of a prime and a square. Short paper by Babaev (1958), mention in Vaughan's The Hardy-Littlewood Method. So $x^2 + p y^2 $   cannot be replaced by $x^2 + p$

Comment: @WillJagy: Is it clear (or heuristically plausible) that these infinitely many integers evading the shape $x^2+p$ also include infinitely many primes? I cannot make much of the original Russian paper, but superficially it looks like a contradiction is reached there assuming an expression $n^2=x^2+p$ (or more generally $n^2=x^k+p$) for certain $n$ to be chosen suitably (which is of course handy, since $n^2-x^2$ factors).

Comment: @JoachimKönig   I've been experimenting with primes $p \equiv 23 \pmod{24}.$  It seems each of those is a square plus a smaller prime,  at least two ways $p < 1000.$ So I'm guessing that Babaev's  missing numbers are mostly composite. Oh, three forms $x^2 + y^2, x^2 + 2 y^2, x^2 + 3 y^2$  represent all other primes.  Now that I think of it, I'll  throw in all   primes  as a square plus prime

Comment: @JoachimKönig   I'm getting that the failures are $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$  If that is always true, the OP's question becomes affirmative using the single fixed form $x^2 + 3 y^2$  Let me check my output   more carefully, mine over a thousand are $1549, 3319, 7549.$

Comment: For what it's worth, there are 15 primes up to $10^9$ which are not of the form $x^2+p$ (for a smaller prime $p$), the largest being $7549$. It's plausible that these examples run out (although it may be hard to prove), see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710032/conjecture-all-but-21-non-square-integers-are-the-sum-of-a-square-and-a-prime

Comment: "odd prime $q\ge 3$" is a nice example of pleonasm

Comment: Experimentally: every prime $q>5$ up to $10^6$ can be written as $x^2+py^2$ with $p<q$ and $p$ prime (hence excluding $p=1$). Call $w(q)$ the minimal such $p$; one easily checks $\limsup_qw(q)=\infty$. For all $5<q<10^6$ has $w(q)<3000$ (only 4 values of $q$ have $w(q)>2000$, namely $q=29567$, $459623$, $791447$, $963191$); for those $5<q<10^6$ equal to $1$ mod 4, $w(q)<500$ with $w(328037)=499$.

Comment: Title of the book by Cox [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437635/is-every-prime-q-of-the-form-x2-py2-for-some-prime-pq#comment1128215_437635) by @BenjaminDickman: [Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2$](https://doi.org/10.1002/9781118400722).

Comment: The paper and book [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437635/is-every-prime-q-of-the-form-x2-py2-for-some-prime-pq#comment1128241_437635) by @WillJagy:  [Babaev - Remark on a paper of Davenport and Heilbronn](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=7493); [Vaughan - The Hardy–Littlewood method](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511470929).

Comment: Could it be deduced from (G)RH that $w(q)\ll_{\varepsilon}q^{\frac12+\varepsilon}$?